# It is possible catch several exceptions with only one try-catch block?

Tags: javascript, exception, closures

In this javascript code `f.init()` control the entire flow of the program:

```
var f = function() {
    return {
        init: function(var1) {
            try {
                f.f1(1)
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
            try {
                f.f2(1)
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
            // ...
            // more try-catch blocks                
            // ...
        },
        f1: function() {
            throw Error('f1 called');
        },
        f2: function() {
            throw Error('f2 called');
        }
    };
}();

f.init();
```

How I could centralize all exceptions management in only one try-catch block? Something like this:

```
var f = function() {
    return {
        init: function(var1) {
            f.f1(1) // this cut the control flow if thrown some error
            f.f2(1) // so this is not called
        },
        f1: function() {
                throw Error('f1 called');
        },
        f2: function() {
                throw Error('f2 called');
        }
    };
}();

try {
    f.init();
} catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

The previous code cut the flow after thrown some error.

Comment: you might want to re-examine your use of exceptions... They don't seem like they're signifying exceptional (unexpected) cases...

Comment: Are you saying you want it to do something whenever an exception occurs, but then continue through the rest of the code in the `try`?

Comment: @james-montagne +1 I would run `f.f2()` even after `f.f1()` thrown some error. But as jondavidjohn +1 says I am not using the `exceptions` concept well.

Comment: I'm not fully sure that we've understood the question...

Comment: @lvaro-g-vicario The idea is not use so many try-catch blocks. But now I understand that `exceptions` pass control to upper levels. So it is not well used if I want continue the flow in the same level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Once an error is thrown, the program flow breaks.

Comment: Correct! Logging will not break the flow. In modern browsers you can even do stuff like console.error, console.warn, console.log

Comment: +1 That is? just breaks? Pass the control to an upper level, right? So maybe in this case I should call some method to alert/log errors but not thrown exceptions. Correct?

Comment: You must be thinking about syntax errors. If you `throw` inside `try{}` program flow jumps to matching `catch{}`, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot . But there is a trick to handle multiple-catch :

```
try{

 try{
   firstTrial();
 }
 catch(e1){
   secondTrial();
 }

}catch(e2){
   thirdTrial();
}
```